# Failing rspec test to authenticate password from Michael Hartl Tutorial

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rspec-rails

At chapter 6 from Michael Hartl tutorial the following piece of test should pass,

```
   describe "with invalid password" do
   let(:user_for_invalid_password) { found_user.authenticate("invalid") }
   it { should_not eq user_for_invalid_password }
   specify { expect(user_for_invalid_password).to be_false }
   end
```

Yet, from the 19 tests, this is the only one which fails.

My model is called Utilisateur (french for User)

Here is the full spec file (fund_user variable is set in the same block, at the end of the file)

```
require 'rails_helper'


describe Utilisateur do

  before do
      @user = Utilisateur.new(nom: "Example User", email: "user@example.com",
                       password: "foobar", password_confirmation: "foobar")
    end

  subject { @user }

  it { should respond_to(:nom) }
  it { should respond_to(:email) }
  it { should respond_to(:password_digest) }
  it { should respond_to(:password) }
  it { should respond_to(:password_confirmation) }
  it { should respond_to(:authenticate) }

  it { should be_valid }

  describe "when name is not present" do
      before { @user.nom = " " }
      it { should_not be_valid }
    end

  describe "when email is not present" do
      before { @user.email = " " }
      it { should_not be_valid }
  end

  describe "when name is too long" do
      before { @user.nom = "a" * 51 }
      it { should_not be_valid }
  end

  describe "when email format is invalid" do
      it "should be invalid" do
        addresses = %w[user@foo,com user_at_foo.org example.user@foo.
                       foo@bar_baz.com foo@bar+baz.com]
        addresses.each do |invalid_address|
          @user.email = invalid_address
          expect(@user).not_to be_valid
        end
      end
    end

  describe "when email format is valid" do
      it "should be valid" do
        addresses = %w[user@foo.COM A_US-ER@f.b.org frst.lst@foo.jp a+b@baz.cn]
        addresses.each do |valid_address|
          @user.email = valid_address
          expect(@user).to be_valid
        end
      end
  end

  describe "when email address is already taken" do
      before do
        user_with_same_email = @user.dup
        user_with_same_email.email = @user.email.upcase
        user_with_same_email.save
      end

      it { should_not be_valid }
  end

  describe "when password is not present" do
    before do
      @user = Utilisateur.new(nom: "Example User", email: "user@example.com",
                       password: " ", password_confirmation: " ")
    end
    it { should_not be_valid }
  end

  describe "when password doesn't match confirmation" do
    before { @user.password_confirmation = "mismatch" }
    it { should_not be_valid }
  end

  describe "with a password that's too short" do
     before { @user.password = @user.password_confirmation = "a" * 5 }
     it { should be_invalid }
  end




  describe "return value of authenticate method" do
     before { @user.save }
     let(:found_user) { Utilisateur.find_by(email: @user.email) }

     describe "with valid password" do
       it { should eq found_user.authenticate(@user.password) }
     end

     describe "with invalid password" do
       let(:user_for_invalid_password) { found_user.authenticate("invalid") }

       it { should_not eq user_for_invalid_password }
       specify { expect(user_for_invalid_password).to be_false }
     end
   end

end
```

And the model file :

```
    class Utilisateur < ActiveRecord::Base

      before_save { self.email = email.downcase }

      validates :nom,  presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }


      VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
      validates :email, presence: true, format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX }, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }

      has_secure_password
      validates :password, length: { minimum: 6 }

end
```

Comment: Please, post here error message which you get.

Comment: actually this is not an error message, just the following failing test notification : 'rspec ./spec/models/utilisateur_spec.rb:125 # Utilisateur return value of authenticate method with invalid password should be false' as it should actually pass

Comment: What if you try to take a new User for the passwords tests? Put the `before { subject.reload }` after your `describe "return value of authenticate method" do before { @user.save }` OR (if this will not work) after `describe "with invalid password" do`.
Not 'new' user, better to say "refresh your instance of a User'.

Comment: Still a single failure. This is very weird as this is the exact same code as the tutorial (amended with model name) ..

Answer (score 0):

If you still need an answer.
You received this mistake from this string:

```
specify { expect(user_for_invalid_password).to be_false }
```

You have to use:

```
specify { expect(user_for_invalid_password).to be_falsey }
```

See info about this in rspec echo:

> 1) User return value of authenticate method with invalid password should be false
>        Failure/Error: specify { expect(user_for_invalid_password).to be_false }
>          expected false to respond to `false?` or perhaps you meant `be false` or `be_falsey`

https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/docs/built-in-matchers

- expect(actual).to be_truthy    # passes if actual is truthy (not nil
  or false)
- expect(actual).to be true      # passes if actual == true
- expect(actual).to be_falsey    # passes if actual is falsy (nil or
  false)
- expect(actual).to be false     # passes if actual == fals